# How do I report a application that is not novel?

Tags: prior-art, us20120226189

How do I alert the Patent Office that the application describes a device that was published over 20 years ago and was on the market up until 1994?  In-other-words, it is not novel!

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are in the time window for free submission of up to three published documents to the USPTO. How to do this is the FAQs and more than a couple of past answers. [Uspto page on third party pre issuance submissions](http://www.uspto.gov/aia_implementation/patents.jsp#heading-7)
Before doing that you might want to look up the record of the case in Uspto public PAIR. Right now it shows that the case is not yet docketed. Looking the image file wrapper you can see the things that the applicant made the examiner aware of already. Not infrequently there are posters who think they have the silver bullet to kill an application but it turns out the claims in the application went quite a bit beyond the prior art. Claims can be hard to dissect. I recommend posting the substance of what you know about and why you see it as covering what the claims claim. You can post it as an answer to your own question.